# Cannot get correct static files after refreshing except index page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, serve

When I refresh page on index route (`/`) and login page (`/login`), it works fine.

However, my website gets error as I refresh on other routes, for example `/user/123456`.

Because no matter what the request is, the browser always gets HTML file.
Thus, both of the content in `main.css` and `main.js` are HTML, and the browser error.

[image]

I have already read the README of create-react-app.
Whether I use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package (`$serve -s  build -p 80`) or express, it will produce the strange bug.

Following is my server code:

```js
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Production Express server running at localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**Edit:** I have figured out where caused the problem.
I created a new project, and compared it to mine. The path of static files in the new project is **absolute**, but in my project is **relative**.
As a result, I delete `"homepage": "."` in the `package.json`.

```js
//package.json
{ ....
  dependencies:{....},
  ....,
- "homepage": "."
}
```

Everything works as expected now. How am I careless...

Comment: It would be helpful to see your webpack config and index.html

Comment: @promisified thanks for response. i use create-react-app to develop and build. should I reject?

Comment: Are you trying to serve the static files created by the build script? If not, I'm not sure why you would need express to serve files given that create react app uses webpack dev server in development?

Comment: yes I use webpack-dev-server when developing. I used `$serve -s build -p 80` to "deploy" my app and encountered the above problem. so I try to use express to slove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out where caused the problem.
I created a new project, and compared it to mine. The path of static files in the new project is **absolute**, but in my project is **relative**.
As a result, I delete `"homepage": "."` in the *package.json*.

```
//package.json
{ ....
 dependencies:{....},
 ....,
- "homepage": "."
}
```

Everything works as expected now. How am I careless...

Answer (score 0):

If your route `/user/**` is defined after `app.get('/*', ...` it might not match because `/*` gets all the requests and returns you index.html.
Try without the `*` or declare the other routes before.

Comment: thanks for response.  `react-route` is client side routing. Do you mean is that I still need to handle server routing manually?

Comment: No, I think that if you get your main.html file on any request it might be because that `app.get('/*'` catches all your requests. So maybe that `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));` isn't well set, I don't see any "build" folder in your file tree, maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, I thought you misunderstood the server part. In your case, you use `serve` as your server. This is a static server provided by [serve]. If you want to use your own `server.js`, you should run `node server.js` or `node server`.

I also did the same things with you and have no this issue. The followings are what I did:

1. `create-react-app my-app`
2. `npm run build`
3. `sudo serve -s build -p 80` (`sudo` for port under 1024)

And I got the results:

[/user/321](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itbtb.png)

I guessed you might forget to build the script. You can try the followings:

1. remove `build/` folder
2. run `npm run build` again

---

Advise: If you want to focus on front-end, you can just use [serve]. It will be easy for you to focus on what you need.

Comment: I found my problem is caused by the homepage setting in the _package.json_.  Thanks for response.